# select COUNT(country) group by country count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get the count of country visit on my site. I have a SQL table with uid, country and date. I'm then trying to pull count from SQL where I need the count in ordered array like

- US - 53
- UK - 47
- CA - 45
- and so on

It's been far to long time since I've played with SQL queries and I believe its my GROUP BY that fails.

```
SELECT COUNT(cfCountry) AS count FROM countryTracking GROUP BY cfCountry
```

But this just returns:

- 8
- 4
- 47
- 2
- 4
- 2
- and so on

How do I make it return the count of the country in ordered with, plus the country in front?

Comment: Is this for `mysql` or Microsoft `sql-server`? You have both engines tagged.

Comment: @SqlZim, I've edited it now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply adding the field you want to show alongside the count should show this in your resultset.

```
SELECT cfCountry, COUNT(cfCountry) AS count
FROM countryTracking c
GROUP BY cfCountry
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I will mark this one as accepted as you wrote what the issue was, thank you and it worked nicely.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a count find like this

```
SELECT 
    country,
    COUNT(country) as count
FROM countryTracking
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY COUNT(country)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(cfCountry) AS COUNT,
       cfCountry
FROM countryTracking
GROUP BY cfCountry
ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```